# Keep the value of the main map after clearing map

Tags: java

I have `mainHolder` map which contains another map `holder` as value I am facing problem when clearing the holder map that I am loosing the vlue of the `apple` key in the `mainHolder` map.

How can I Keep the value of the mainHolder map after Clearing the `holder` map?

**Code**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;


public class Generator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedHashMap<String, Object> holder = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        final HashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Object>> mainHolder = new LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Object>>();

        holder.put("firstName", "Alex");
        holder.put("lastName", "Cruz");
        mainHolder.put("apple", holder);
        holder.clear(); //After Clearing the map I am loosing the value in the mainHolder for 'apple'
        holder.put("quantity", 13);
        mainHolder.put("apple", holder);
        System.out.println("Test");

    }
}
```

**mainHolder**
should contain at the end the following:

[apple:[firstName: Fadi, lastName: Cruz, quantity:13]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because you are using the same key.

> If the map previously contains a mapping for the key, the old value
>   is replaced.

**Update**

> <>.add(map) will put a reference to map in the list, so it's not a
>   copy. When you then do map.clear() afterwards, it erases the content
>   of the map in the list too, because it is the very same object. Do
>   <>.add(map.clone()) instead or (preferably) do map = new HashMap<>();

**solution**

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Object> holder = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
final HashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Object>> mainHolder = new LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, Object>>();

holder.put("firstName", "Alex");
holder.put("lastName", "Cruz");
mainHolder.put("apple", holder);

holder = new LinkedHashMap<>();

LinkedHashMap<String, Object> temp = mainHolder.get("apple");
temp.put("quantity",13);
mainHolder.put("apple",temp);

System.out.println(mainHolder);
```

Comment: I my case I need to add `holder` content to the  `mainHolder` key without changing the key also updating the value of the key `apple`